# Scrolling with Anchors, Class and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**First:** I'm sorry in advance for my english. This is not my first language. :)

## The Situation

**So, this is the deal:** I'm trying to make a single button where the user can click and then it will automatically scroll down to the next DIV. Each DIV's have the class `.anchor`, and the one that is "selected" have another class called `.anchor--selected`. When you arrive at the last one, the arrow rotate to 180deg, so the user can see it will go all the way up. Yay! This part is working!

**And the great part is:** I don't have to give any of my div a name, since I don't know how many there will be.

But, the next part it's kind of tricky... I mean, for someone who doesn't work a lot with jQuery. (I'm learning, slowly, but I'm learning!)

## The Problem

Now, when I'm in the middle of the page while scrolling and I decide instead to click, it go all the way up to the page. So, I tried a little something, and it seem to work. But when I'm in the last anchor, and I scroll too much, it giving me this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined(…)`.

## The CodePen

So here the [link](http://codepen.io/Naeya/pen/Bpwypm) to the not so working anchor button with scrolling.

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".scroll-down-arrow").on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var currentAnchor = $(".anchor--selected");;
      var nextAnchor = currentAnchor.next(".anchor");
      var firstAnchor = $(".anchor").first();
      var lastAnchor = $(".anchor").last();
    
      if(currentAnchor.is(lastAnchor)) {
       currentAnchor.removeClass("anchor--selected");
       firstAnchor.addClass("anchor--selected");
         
       $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop:firstAnchor.offset().top});
       $(this).removeClass("prev").addClass("next");
      } else {
       currentAnchor.removeClass("anchor--selected");
       nextAnchor.addClass("anchor--selected");
       $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop:nextAnchor.offset().top});
    
       if(currentAnchor.is(lastAnchor.prev())) {
        $(this).removeClass("next").addClass("prev");
       }
      }
     });
    
     $(window).on("scroll", function() {
      var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
      var currentAnchor = $(".anchor--selected");;
      var nextAnchor = currentAnchor.next(".anchor");
      var prevAnchor = currentAnchor.prev(".anchor");
      var firstAnchor = $(".anchor").first();
      var lastAnchor = $(".anchor").last();
    
      console.log("scrollPos : " + scrollPos + " currentAnchor : " + nextAnchor.offset().top);
      console.log(scrollPos <= nextAnchor.offset().top);
      console.log("Current anchor is last? : " + currentAnchor.is(lastAnchor));
    
      if(scrollPos >= nextAnchor.offset().top) {
       if(currentAnchor.is(lastAnchor)) {
        currentAnchor.removeClass("anchor--selected");
        prevAnchor.addClass("anchor--selected");
       
        $(".scroll-down-arrow").removeClass("prev").addClass("next");
       } else {
        currentAnchor.removeClass("anchor--selected");
        nextAnchor.addClass("anchor--selected");
    
        if(currentAnchor.is(firstAnchor)) {
         $(".scroll-down-arrow").removeClass("next").addClass("prev");
        }
       }
      }
     });
    });
```

```css
  
    #one, #two, #three, #four, #five {
     padding: 15px;
    }
  
    #one {
     height: 500px;
     background-color: #f0f8ff;
    }
    
    #two {
     height: 300px;
     background-color: #7fffd4;
    }
    
    #three {
     height: 150px;
     background-color: #deb887;
    }
    
    #four {
     height: 600px;
     background-color: #5f9ea0;
    }
    
    #five {
     height: 1000px;
     background-color: #f3b9c6;
    }
    
    .scroll-down-arrow {
     width: 50px;
     height: 50px;
     border-radius: 50%;
     background-color: #010101;
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 25px;
     right: 25px;
     cursor: pointer;
     -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
     transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
    }
    
    .scroll-down-arrow.prev {
     -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
     transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
    
    .scroll-down-arrow.next {
     -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
     transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    
    .scroll-down-arrow i {
     color: #f1f1f1;
     font-size: 24px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
     <div id="one" class="anchor anchor--selected">
      This is my first div
        </div>
    
     <div id="two" class="anchor">
      This is my second div
     </div>
    
     <div id="three" class="anchor">
      This is my third div
     </div>
    
     <div id="four" class="anchor">
      This is my fourth div
     </div>
    
     <div id="five" class="anchor">
      This is my fifth div
     </div>
    
     <div class="scroll-down-arrow next"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    </main>
```

## Conclusion

So, I've tried to reuse my code on the "scroll click" and put it on the "window scroll". But I think I'm missing something and I would like some help to get throught it.

Thank you very much and feel free to ask questions! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you aren't testing to see if there *is* another `.anchor`, jQuery is throwing an error. Just test to see if there is a next `.anchor`.

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".scroll-down-arrow").on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var currentAnchor = $(".anchor--selected");;
            var nextAnchor = currentAnchor.next(".anchor");
            var firstAnchor = $(".anchor").first();
            var lastAnchor = $(".anchor").last();

            if(currentAnchor.is(lastAnchor)) {
                currentAnchor.removeClass("anchor--selected");
                firstAnchor.addClass("anchor--selected");

                $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop:firstAnchor.offset().top});
                $(this).removeClass("prev").addClass("next");
            } else {
                currentAnchor.removeClass("anchor--selected");
                nextAnchor.addClass("anchor--selected");
                $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop:nextAnchor.offset().top});

                if(currentAnchor.is(lastAnchor.prev())) {
                    $(this).removeClass("next").addClass("prev");
                }
            }
        });

        $(window).on("scroll", function() {
            var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
            var currentAnchor = $(".anchor--selected");
        if(currentAnchor.next(".anchor").length){
          var nextAnchor = currentAnchor.next(".anchor");
        } else {
          var nextAnchor = $(".anchor:first");
        }
            var prevAnchor = currentAnchor.prev(".anchor");
            var firstAnchor = $(".anchor").first();
            var lastAnchor = $(".anchor").last();

            console.log("scrollPos : " + scrollPos + " currentAnchor : " + nextAnchor.offset().top);
            console.log(scrollPos <= nextAnchor.offset().top);
            console.log("Current anchor is last? : " + currentAnchor.is(lastAnchor));

            if(scrollPos >= nextAnchor.offset().top) {
                if(currentAnchor.is(lastAnchor)) {
                    currentAnchor.removeClass("anchor--selected");
                    prevAnchor.addClass("anchor--selected");

                    $(".scroll-down-arrow").removeClass("prev").addClass("next");
                } else {
                    currentAnchor.removeClass("anchor--selected");
                    nextAnchor.addClass("anchor--selected");

                    if(currentAnchor.is(firstAnchor)) {
                        $(".scroll-down-arrow").removeClass("next").addClass("prev");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yak613/up6rLqou/

**Note:** This doesn't work when scrolling up, I will attempt to fix that.

Comment: Oh! Thanks! I should have thought about this before. Haha! I'm gonna try to make it work when scrolling up! :)